# how to create empty editable row when user click add button using ext js5.1

Tags: extjs

How to create empty editable row when user click add button.![enter image description here][1]

i am new to ext js,here iam sharing my requirement.i tried in related retirement in search engines.i didn't get any code.
below i am sharing requirement image.
here my requirement is when user click "addlayer" button the editable new row will cretaed.After user enter layerid,polictnum,limit values click "calculate losses" button calculate the partof,attachment,expectedlosses values.and how to impleemnt edit and delete button.
any one please share related code.
here i am using visual studio 2012

Answer (score 4):

Here is a sample code:

```
var grid = this.lookupReference('grid reference'), // you can even do it differently if grid component or it's view is passed to your handler function
    store = grid.getStore(); // get the store
var rec = store.insert(0, {}); // insert an empty record to your store
grid.getPlugin('celleditor').startEdit(0, 0); // enable editing at the first column of the new record in your grid.
```

Comment: Hi Seram, thanks for responding to me.the above code is not working can u please share any solution to me.

Comment: Share how you are doing?